# AjaxControlToolkit Version=4.1.60501.0 - Error: AjaxControlToolkit requires ASP.NET Ajax 4.0 scripts

Tags: ajax, toolkitscriptmanager

I'm getting this error:

Error: AjaxControlToolkit requires ASP.NET Ajax 4.0 scripts. Ensure the correct version of the scripts are referenced. If you are using an ASP.NET ScriptManager, switch to the ToolkitScriptManager in AjaxControlToolkit.dll.

I've searched Hi and Low and can not resolve this. When I went to VS2008 I had the same issue and resolved it with changing my web.config

Now I ma running VS 2012 express. I've installed AjaxControlToolkit version 4.1.60501.0

Web.config:

```
 <compilation debug="false" targetFramework="4.5">
 <assemblies>
 <add assembly="AjaxControlToolkit, Version=4.1.60501.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=28f01b0e84b6d53e"/>
 <add assembly="System.Web.Extensions.Design, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
 <add assembly="System.Design, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B03F5F7F11D50A3A"/>
 <add assembly="System.Windows.Forms, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089"/>
 </assemblies>
```

and

```
 <controls>
 <add tagPrefix="cc1" namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" assembly="AjaxControlToolkit"/>
 </controls>
```

In ASPX I have:

```
 <cc1:ToolkitScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
 </cc1:ToolkitScriptManager>
```

And I'm getting the above error. I know the Toolkit DLL is the correct version.

I am also running VS2008 / Ajax 3.5 on the same machine, but I cleared out the Temporary ASP.Net Files folder of all other projects and still have the issue. When I run this new VS2012 project, a ROOT folder is created in the in the Temp folder and the AjaxControlToolkit.DLL in that folder is version 4.1.60501.0

What needs to change?

Thanks Much,
Jim